Using Selenium-Java and WebDriverManager to do browser recording on multiple tabs
We are using selenium-java v4.23.1 and WedDriverManager v5.9.2 and we are experimenting on browser recording for troubleshooting failed tests.
We already put tab recording to work following the WedDriverManager documentation page (section on Tab Recording), but could only have it working for one tab in the browser.
We tried different approaches. In one of them we were able to start the recording on tab 1 and then on tab 2 providing different files names, and we can see the recording icon on both the tab headers, but it doesn't create two video files, only one. And this one video file shows the interactions done on tab1 only.
Our tests use multiple tabs, where each one logs into different portals of our platform and perform actions there. Furthermore, the tests “move” from one tab to the other where business actions are done.
Is it possible to record multiple tabs in the browser? Into a single video file or even one video file per tab?
The only way we think it would work is for every time we change tab in the test, would have to stop the recording for the current tab and start a new recording on the new tab, and so on. That means multiple video files for these type of tests.
Would like to know what are the alternatives to put it to work in this context. It would be an important feature to have.

Assuming that you're using 1 browser per instance, one way to have recording of the tests would be to :

Use a VNC server on the system running the browser
Select a VNC client of your choice (I've used VernacularVNC) and write script to connect to the VNC server
Capture the frames and use ffmpeg utility to convert those images into video

Alternatively,
Selenium grid's docker images are now available with support for video recording (and even uploading that to a s3 bucket).
The link of which is : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium?tab=readme-ov-file#video-recording-and-uploading
You can run your browser test in this grid which will auto generate the video recording for you.

Also, if you're using chrome based browsers in the tests. You can leverage the casting APIs to cast the stream into a video file (again leveraging ffmpeg to achieve the file)
